# Wordpress print embed code on post for easy copy

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have Wordpress site and want to print the share embed code at the bottom of the post like on this website http://www.expansys.com/infographics/facebook-v-tv/

Someone told me I can use something like

```
$(".theclass").focus(function(){
    this.select();
})
```

Unfortunately I don't know where to start and was hoping for some pointers. I couldn't find any plugins to do this either.

Comment: When you say "print the share embed code", do you literally mean have it printed out of a printer?

Comment: No it I meant to print out on the screen in a textarea as per you answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the poster just wanted to be able to select all the text inside of the textarea when it's clicked (like in the example website he gave), then if you look at the html source on the page, you'll see that they don't use a jQuery solution, they just call

```
<textarea onclick="this.select();">
```

Here's a jsFiddle showing that this will work (at least in all the most up-to-date versions of IE9, Firefox 5, Chrome 12, Opera, and Safari), http://jsfiddle.net/QpfAj/.